# How to convert a decimal number into ratio in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a requirement to divide a number into multiple parts and trying to find a way to present number in the ratio.

```
mysql> select quantity/splits from products;
```

Where quantity is 1 and split can be 2 or 3. The output I get is now .50 or .33 whereas I am looking for output 1/2 or 1/3.

So I wanted to find out if there is a way to cover decimal number back to ratio.

Any ideas?

Comment: So... What have you tried? We're not here to code for you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13244811/find-ratio-for-any-number-of-variables-in-php <-- seems to answer your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/` is a division operator, to build a string try:

```
SELECT CONCAT(quantity,'/',splits) AS fraction FROM products;
```

Or:

```
SELECT CONCAT(quantity,':',splits) AS ratio FROM products;
```